# What is difference between Local and Global Gauss bonnet thm????(aspect of utilization)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Hi I'm a student studying differential geometry. Here is the problem bothering me.

Here is the Gauss-Bonnet thm I've known that

Let the surface M and its subset S(2-dimensional segment of the M).

(Global) $\int\int_M K dM + \int_{\partial M} k_g ds$ = $2\pi\chi(M)$ - (sum of the external angles)

(Local) $\int\int_S K dM + \int_{\partial S} k_g ds$ = $2\pi$ - (sum of the external angles)

Here $K $ is a guassian curvature for surface, $M$

$\chi(M)$ is a euler characteristic of the M,

And $k_g$ is a geodesic curvature  when we think about the  boundary of M(=$\partial M$)

==============================================================

I'm confused Where, When Should I properly Choose and Use the one of them.

## What is difference of them at the point of the utilizing???

Here are some examples make me confused.(This questions are in my textbook.)
Mt text book solve all of them by Global Gauss bonnet thm

$Q1)$ $ M : x^2 + y^2 - z^2 =0$ (conic section) and $T: y+\sqrt3z=3$(plain)
For curve  $\beta(t)(=M \cap T )$ on $S$, What is $ \vert \int_{\beta} k_g ds\vert $ ?

(tip) Gaussian curvature of the M is $0$.

$Q2)$ $M$ : rotation of a $y=2+sinx $ ($x \in R$)

$S$ : rotation of a $y=2+sinx $ ($0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$) whose axis is $X-axis$

Find the $\int\int_S K dM$

Plus, $Q3)$
Sphere, $M : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =4$
$S:(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$  Find the $\int\int_{S \cap M} K dM$

====================================================================
Here is my trial

$Q1)$ Since $\beta(t)$ is a smooth curve who lying on the plain so its dimension is $2$.
Hence, sum of the external angle is $0$ . Therefore $ \vert \int_{\beta} k_g ds\vert=0$

$Q2)$ Since $S(=X(u,v)) =(u, (2+sin u)cosv,(2+sinu)sinv) $ , S can be expressed as $X(u,v)$ (2 dimensional segments.)
So I've tried to solve by local Gaussian bonnet thm but failed.

But my textbook solve all of them by using the Global Gauss-bonnet thm and its answers were$ \sqrt2\pi$ and $0$ respectively.

## I can't understand which point I was wrong.

Plus the $Q3$'s answer was $2 \pi -4$. I don't know which should I use between two of them.

Please give me some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Which book is that by the way? If you think of the Euler characteristic as being, for a polyhedron, the number of vertices minus the number of edges plus the number of faces, then this makes it plausible that there is a similar formula, using external angles at vertices ($0$-dimensional), the total curvature of the boundary curve ($1$-dimensional) and the total Gaussian curvature ($2$-dimensional).

Comment: The local version usually deals with a triangular or polygonal region bounding a surface $S$. So the topology is assumed to be similar to that of a polygon and its interior, which has Euler characteristic equal to $1$.

Comment: Are you sure the answer to Q1 is $\sqrt{2} \pi$?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure the answer was written as  '$\sqrt2\pi$'

Comment: Isn't these two the same things? The local GB is just restricting the consideration to $M=S$.

Comment: I thought like that first time, But I couldn't applied in solving the above question. Coz, The answer was different.

Comment: The Gaussian curvature of a cone is $0$ away from the vertex. By cutting the cone with $2$ different planes and applying Gauss-Bonnet, this shows that the total geodesic curvature of $2$ different ellipses cut out by 2 different planes is the same. So it is enough to do the calculation by cutting out the cone with $z=1$. :)

Comment: This was my hint for Q1.

Comment: For Q2, the Euler characteristic of $M$ is $0$, so it is enough to calculate the difference between the geodesic curvature of the circle obtained by rotating $(0,2)$ and that of the circle obtained by rotating $(2\pi,2)$.

Comment: For Q3, I am getting $(4-2\sqrt{2})\pi$, which is different from what you wrote. I did it in 2 different ways. Maybe I am wrong... I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your help, mr. @Malkoun . I'll try it again